# The difference in the Marvel Now! banners

Tags: marvel

So on the Marvel Now! comics, the bottom portion always has the red banner that has like "Join the ReEVOLUTION!" and what-not. So what is the difference between the red banners and the blue ones?

Answer (score 4):

**The Marvel Now! promotional is designed to showcase Marvel's continued development of digital/augmented reality versions of their comics. The differing colors distinguish variant cover printings. The red is the first printing, the blue is the second cover variant and the green is the third variant. Occasionally there are more than one third variant, but they are all green after that.**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**From the [Marvel Press Release](http://www.comicbookmovie.com/fansites/JoshWildingNewsAndReviews/news/?a=62986) at ComicBookMovie.com :**

> Every comic book bearing the Marvel NOW! branding includes a code for a free digital copy of that same comic on the Marvel Comics app for iOS and Android devices. Additionally, each issue #1 of Marvel NOW! series features special augmented reality content available exclusive through the Marvel AR app – including cover recaps, behind the scenes features and more that add value to your reading experience at no additional cost.
>
> "This is the natural next step of the Marvel ReEvolution, as we evolve every facet of Marvel publishing," explained Joe Quesada, Chief Creative Officer, Marvel Entertainment. "You’ve seen us craft new digital storytelling formats like Marvel Infinite Comics and bring added value to our comics with Marvel AR. Now our print comics leap into the future with a cinematic new look for our covers, exciting new designs for our biggest characters and stories that will send you on the kind of journey you can only get at Marvel."